# Flatten Array In Object

Tags: arrays, json, jq, flatten

Is there an elegant way to replicate an object for each array item within?

```
printf '{"a":"","b":[{},{}]}' | jq '{a:.a,b:.b[]}'
{"a":"","b":{}}
{"a":"","b":{}}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: It requires manually rebuilding the object. Someone on freenode did make a good suggestion. Although it still requires manually rebuilding the object, it is a bit more elegant: .b=.b[].

Comment: Well if your goal is to split up the inner array of objects into new separate objects, of course you're going to have to "rebuild" new objects. How do _you_ define "elegant"?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a programmatic way to expand all array-valued keys of an arbitrary JSON object:

```
def blowup(a): 
  def b(f): {(f): (.[f] | if type == "array" then .[] else . end)};

  if a|length == 0 then {} else b(a[0]) + blowup(a[1:]) end;

blowup(keys)
```

Example:

Input: {a:0, b: [1,2], c: [3,4]}

Output:

```
{"a":0,"b":1,"c":3}
{"a":0,"b":2,"c":3}
{"a":0,"b":1,"c":4}
{"a":0,"b":2,"c":4}
```